# How do I write an mac npapi plugin with OpenGL?

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin, npruntime

I was looking through the header files and  I saw the openGL drawing model, so I was busy switching everything in my plugin from CoreGraphics when I saw online that, apparently, the openGL drawing model doesn't actually exist and never will...

Can any of you help me out or link me to a good tutorial or resource that will help me do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only supported way to use OpenGL w/ a Mac NPAPI plugin is to use the CoreAnimation drawing model with CAOpenGLLayer.

You'll probably want to read [Stuart Morgan's blog post](http://www.escapedthoughts.com/weblog/geek/P110308-mac-npapi-plugins.writeback) on the topic of Mac drawing models.

Note that on Safari you'll use [CoreAnimation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI%3aCoreAnimationDrawingModel) and on other browsers you'll use [InvalidatingCoreAnimation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI%3aInvalidatingCoreAnimation); it's going to work about the same way, but with Invalidating you need to call [NPN_InvalidateRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_InvalidateRect) each time.

[FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) has an example of drawing in all of these models; it was cludged into the [BasicMediaPlayer](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/tree/master/examples/BasicMediaPlayer/Mac) example.  Even if you decide not to use FireBreath you may find the [code](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginAuto/Mac/PluginWindowMacCA.mm) or the [docs](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Event+models+and+drawing+models) instructive.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the links.. Much clearer now.  Do you know if it is at all possible to use OpenGL on windows?

Comment: It is; the easiest way is to make a windowless plugin, in which case you get an HWND and can just set things up as usual. If you do windowless then the only way I know to make it work is to render offscreen and then blit to the hDC

Comment: I meant windowed plugin, not windowless